# Is there a way to copy a file on save vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

### Workflow to automate

- code file `file` in folder `B`
- copy file to folder `A`

Is there a way to have this file/multiple files copy on save in vscode?

### Context

I have two folder `A` and `B`. Folder `B` has some code in it that has to be copy pasted into folder `A` for it to be executed. But version control is on folder `B` for this file so I have to code there.

Comment: you can create a `multi-command` (extension) and bind it to `Ctrl+S`, the multi command saves the file and executes a task to copy file(s)

Comment: Looks like it could work, but not sure if can Itegrated it with my vim workflow.

Do you know if there is a way to enable it to a specific file/folder ?

Comment: you can give the current file path (full or relative) to a shell script and that will decide if it will copy, or just copy always file X and Y from folder B to folder A on any save.

Comment: I would suggest making an extension that contributes that specific command and enables a code action for it.  Then you can put that command into a `runOnSave` setting.

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly did it, so I share it! Using both Visual Studio Code extensions : multi command (from @ryuta46) and command runner (from @edonet) I can add a 'multi-command' triggered on 'Ctrl+s' shortkey (when saving file) that copy the file to another directory:

**Add into settings.json**
Create a new 'multi command' named copyFile : adjust the destination as needed. This command save the file, wait 2 seconds, and copy to another location.

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
{
    "command": "multiCommand.copyFile",
    "label": "Copy file to another location",
    "description": "copy the current $file to another root hard-coded destination, require 'command-runner' plugin.",
    "interval": 2,
    "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.files.save",
        {
            "command": "command-runner.run",
            "args": { "command": "cp \"${file}\" \"x:/${relativeFile}\"" }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

**Add into keybindings.json**
Trigger the previously defined copyFile multicommand on 'Ctrl+s'

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": { 
            "command": "multiCommand.copyFile"
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single macro extension, like  [Multi-Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  Make this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { 
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.files.save",
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "cp '${file}' '${relativeFileDirname}\\copyTo'\u000D"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `sendSequence` command sends the argument text to the terminal - the sample script assumes a bash-like shell.

As you can see, it saves and then copies the **current file** to the `copyTo` folder which is under the same parent directory as the current file.

The `\u000D` is a return so the command runs immediately without manually having to hit return.